# my image frame is not working in cell

Tags: iphone, image, uitableview

i added image in each cell of a cell table view.iam not ale to set my image frame plz help me in doing this.

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
      UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,   lblzip.frame.size.height+lblzip.frame.origin.y+2,30,30)];
                        myImageView.tag = 120;


                        myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"call.png"];

                        [cell.imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];

     cell.imageView.image=myImageView.image;                            


                        cell.imageView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;


                        UITapGestureRecognizer *tapped = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imageSelectedInTable:)];

                        [cell.imageView addGestureRecognizer:tapped];
                        [tapped release];

  }
```

but my image width and height are not 30. its like image in resources file.

my research gives me a idea to use layout subviews. how to call and use them

```
   -(void)layoutsubviews
     {
      }
```

Comment: Show your real code. What you've got there would never compile, and it makes no sense.

Comment: Flagged as very low quality.

Answer (score 1):

Your code makes no sense.

1. You are referring to `cell` but there is no variable called `cell`. You have forgotten to call `dequeue` and create the cell
2. You have two different image views:

   ```
   UIImageView *myImageView = ...
   ```

   and

   ```
   cell.imageView
   ```

This cannot be your real code. It would never compile. No one can help you if you do not show your *real* code.

As your code stands right now, the answer to your question would be: you are creating `myImageView` with size `30,30` but you are never even putting it into your cell so it's irrelevant. You have a different thing called `cell.imageView` and that's the image view you are seeing.

EDIT: Now you've changed your code. But you are still setting the frame of the wrong image view. You are setting `cell.imageView`'s *image* to `myImageView`'s *image*. But that has nothing to do with the size of the image or the frame of the image view. What I said is still true: you are creating `myImageView` with size `30,30` but you are never even putting it into your cell so it's irrelevant.

Comment: i have done all those like creating cell dequeue

Comment: wats my problem is my image frame is width and height are 30

Comment: but its not responding for frame

Comment: show. your. real. code. please.

Comment: its compiled no problem but the the size is small as in in my resources folder

Comment: cell.imageView.image=myImageView.image; i just added this line

Comment: It doesn't compile! What is `cell`? You never declare anything called `cell` but you refer to it. That's impossible.

Comment: http://pastie.org/7318210

Comment: i have so many lables created in each cell

Comment: No, I don't. Show me the real code. I can handle it! I've seen code before. - In your pastie, the answer is the same as before: `cell.imageView` is not `myImageView`, and `myImageView` is not in the cell, so you're setting the frame of the wrong image view.

Comment: cell.imageView.image=myImageView.image;

Comment: i added my image to cell as shown above

Comment: its really fine and compiled no problem

Comment: is it necessary to use  -(void)layoutsubviews
 i had gone through lot of research.